# Compare 2 files

Tags: c, file

I have a problem, I need to make a program which will compare two files.
If in first file I have:

```
Milk
Sugar
Eggs
```

and in the second file I have

```
Vanilla
Soda
Sugar
```

I want to show the the line which appear in both files.

I don't have a lot of experience with c, but I tried something.
But my question is how I will show Sugar as output if they are not on the same line?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX 100

void equal (char*lineone,char*linetwo){
    if(strcmp(lineone,linetwo)==0){
        printf("%s",lineone);
    }
}
int main(){
    FILE *fp1,*fp2;
    fp1=fopen("D:/aici/file1.txt","r");
    fp2=fopen("D:/aici/file2.txt","r");
    char buff[MAX],buff1[MAX];
    int i=0;
    while((fgets(buff,MAX,fp1)!=NULL)&&(fgets(buff1,MAX,fp2))!=NULL){
            //i++;
            equal(buff,buff1);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can, and should, edit your own question to fix trivial syntax issues.  I've done it for you.  It is worth using copy'n'paste on compilable code to make sure there are no similar trivial errors.  Make sure there are no tabs in what you copy, paste it into the text window, make sure that looks OK (ignore the preview).  Then select the code and use the **`{}`** button above the edit box to indent the code.  Now take a look at the preview to ensure it is what you intended.  You should check that `fp1` and `fp2` are not null before using them.

Comment: Thank you, I saw that I forgot to replace lione with lineone.

Comment: Read the two files into two arrays, sort the arrays, then walk the arrays sequentially to find duplicates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should do (for performence reasons) is to save all the words in to two buffers and then compare them.
But , you can also do it with a little change in your implementation ,
Just need to seperate the loop to one main loop and one inner loop so you will get the effect that for each word in file 1 it will compare all words in file 2, again , very slow method when comparing to just save all the words first and only then compare each other.

```
void equal (char*lione,char*linetwo){
    if(strcmp(lione,linetwo)==0){
        printf("%s",lineone);
    }
}
int main(){
    FILE *fp1,*fp2;
    fp1=fopen("D:/aici/file1.txt","r");
    fp2=fopen("D:/aici/file2.txt","r");
    char buff[MAX],buff1[MAX];
    int i=0;
    while(fgets(buff,MAX,fp1)!=NULL) {
          while(fgets(buff1,MAX,fp2))!=NULL){
           //i++;
            equal(buff,buff1);
          }

         rewind(fp2);
     }

}
```

Comment: When I compile and run your update, I get nothing I don't know why. And in both files I have a word in common. That the result should be that word.

Comment: @Eratys Is there a newline on the last line?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY what do you mean?

Comment: @Eratys E.g `"Sugar\n"` in first file. `"Sugar"` in second file. `"Sugar\n"` not equal `"Sugar"`.

Comment: Recall `fgets` reads *up to and including* the `'\n'`. So on each call to `fgets` `buff` contains a `'\n'` as the final char, (unless you properly remove it), and if the final line does not contain a proper POSIX *end-of-line* (e.g. `'\n'`) then you will be comparing some words with a `'\n'` on the end, and some without. So above in the second file where `Sugar` is on the last line, if your file does not contain a POSIX eol, `"Sugar\n"` read from file 1 will never match `"Sugar"` read from file 2.

Comment: If there is only one word per line you can use fscanf instead which will ignore all eols

Comment: Then I will use fscanf, thanks so much for all the advice. :d

Comment: While you *can* use `fscanf` in this case, you are far better served learning and using *line oriented input* routines (e.g. `fgets` or `getline`) for line-oriented input. Regardless of the method you use, you must validate your reads.

Comment: And if I want to see if a word which is in first file,but  its not in second file and show the word I need to do again with 2 loops, no?

Comment: @Eratys Then it is another problem and you should post another question on StackOverflow.

Comment: @Eratys You need two loops if you want to check if each word in the 1st file does not appear in the 2nd otherwise , if you want to check only one word one loop is enough , you simply iyerating all the words in the 2nd file and makesure none is equal to the word.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from the comment, whether you continue using `fgets` (recommended), or you recognize that you can also use `fscanf` and not worry about removing the `'\n'` from each word, you need to *validate* each step of your program. While `fscanf` may appear easier at first, you may want to brush up on `man fscanf` and determine how you will control the `'\n'` that will be left, unread, in each of your file streams.

The following is a short example, continuing with `fgets`, showing how you can test for, and remove, each of the trailing `'\n'` read and included in your `buff` by `fgets`. (as well as reasonable validations for each step). (note: I'm presuming that since your input is a single word, a 256-char buffer is sufficient -- given the longest word in the *unabridged* dictionary is 28 characters, but you can also validate whether `fgets` has made a complete read of each line, or if additional characters remain unread)

The following code expects the filenames for each of the files to be given as the first two arguments to the program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXC 256

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc < 3) { /* validate 2 arguments given */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient input.\n"
                        "usage: %s file1 file2\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    char buf1[MAXC] = "",               /* declare buf1 */
         buf2[MAXC] = "";               /* declare buf2 */
    FILE *f1 = fopen (argv[1], "r"),    /* open file 1 */
         *f2 = fopen (argv[2], "r");    /* open file 2 */

    if (!f1) {  /* validate file 1 open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "file open failed '%s'\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    if (!f2) {  /* validate file 2 open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "file open failed '%s'\n", argv[2]);
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets (buf1, MAXC, f1)) {    /* read each word in file 1 */
        size_t len1 = strlen (buf1);    /* get length */

        if (len1 && buf1[len1 - 1] == '\n')
            buf1[--len1] = 0;       /* overwrite '\n' with nul-byte */

        while (fgets (buf2, MAXC, f2)) {    /* read each in file 2 */
            size_t len2 = strlen (buf2);

            if (len2 && buf2[len2 - 1] == '\n')
                buf2[--len2] = 0;   /* overwrite '\n' with nul-byte */

            if (len1 != len2)       /* if lengths differ, not equal */
                continue;           /* get next word from file 2 */

            if (strcmp (buf1, buf2) == 0)   /* compare strings */
                printf ("%s\n", buf1);      /* print if equal */
        }
        rewind (f2);    /* rewind f2, clear EOF */
    }
    fclose (f1);    /* close f1 */
    fclose (f2);    /* close f2 */

    return 0;
}
```

(note: the length check `if (len1 != len2)` is just an efficiency check that prevents calling `strcmp` unless the words are equal in length. A simple comparison on the lengths (which you already have) is much less expensive than a full function call to `strcmp` every time. (note, this is a really small savings, that you can remove if you like))

**Input Files (intentionally no POSIX-eol)**

The datafiles were intentionally created without POSIX end-of-lines to demonstrate it makes no difference to the outcome if you properly handle the newline removal.

```
$ cat dat/f1cmp.txt
Milk
Sugar
Eggs

$ cat dat/f2cmp.txt
Vanilla
Soda
Sugar
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/fgets_cmp_words dat/f1cmp.txt dat/f2cmp.txt
Sugar
```

Look things over and concentrate on the validations. Let me know if you have any further questions.

---

### Showing Where Words Differ

To show where the words differ, you only need to modify the inner loop. You can do a simple comparison by looping over the characters in `buf1` and `buf2` and stopping when the first difference is located. You can continue for the two cases above (1) where the lengths differ; and (2) where the return of `strcmp != 0`, or you can just do a single test following a non-zero return from `strcmp`.

The modifications to the inner-loop above is shown below. I don't know what output format you are looking for, so I have just output the words that differ and shown the character at which the words begin to differ (zero-based indexing):

```
    while (fgets (buf2, MAXC, f2)) {    /* read each in file 2 */
        size_t len2 = strlen (buf2);
        int i = 0;

        if (len2 && buf2[len2 - 1] == '\n')
            buf2[--len2] = 0;   /* overwrite '\n' with nul-byte */

        if (len1 != len2) {     /* if lengths differ, not equal */
                                /* locate & output difference */
            for (i = 0; buf1[i] == buf2[i]; i++) {}
            printf ("%s & %s differ at char %d (%c != %c)\n",
                    buf1, buf2, i, buf1[i], buf2[i]);
            continue;              /* get next word from file 2 */
        }

        if (strcmp (buf1, buf2) == 0)        /* compare strings */
            printf ("%s\n", buf1);           /* print if equal  */
        else {                    /* locate & output difference */
            for (i = 0; buf1[i] == buf2[i]; i++) {}
            printf ("%s & %s differ at char %d (%c != %c)\n",
                    buf1, buf2, i, buf1[i], buf2[i]);
        }
    }
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/fgets_cmp_wrds dat/f1cmp.txt dat/f2cmp.txt
Milk & Vanilla differ at char 0 (M != V)
Milk & Soda differ at char 0 (M != S)
Milk & Sugar differ at char 0 (M != S)
Sugar & Vanilla differ at char 0 (S != V)
Sugar & Soda differ at char 1 (u != o)
Sugar
Eggs & Vanilla differ at char 0 (E != V)
Eggs & Soda differ at char 0 (E != S)
Eggs & Sugar differ at char 0 (E != S)
```

Look it over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: And I I want to show their difference, I have a solution, but I need to know if it's a good method. To read both files with getc and then to compare them with an if(buffer!=buffer2) putchar(buffer) putchar(buffer2)

Comment: You can do it that way, the problem you have is dealing with the remaining characters following the point they begin to differ. Since you already have `buf1` and `buf2`, why not simply `for (int i = 0; buf1[i] && buf2[i] && (buf1[i] == buf2[i]); i++)`? Then `if (i = len1) {they are equal} else {they differ beginning at i}` Or, after the `len1 == len2` check, just `for (int i = 0; i < len1; i++) buf1[i] == buf2[i]`?

Comment: I tried your method, but the output it's strange. I need to use the for loop in 2x while loops?

Comment: Take a look at the addition to the answer showing how to determine where the words first differ.